# Use of unresolved identifier 'numbers'

Tags: swift, closures, swift2

I'm following Apple's - The Swift Programming Language iBook and I have to work with closures.

```
numbers.map({
   (number: Int) -> Int in
   let result = 3 * number
   return result
})
```

When I try to insert this piece of code (from the book) in XCode's playground, I get this: "Use of unresolved identifier 'numbers'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define your numbers first!!

```
let numbers = [1,2,3]
let modified = numbers.map({
    (number: Int) -> Int in
    let result = 3 * number
    return result
})
print(modified) // [3, 6, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to initiate the "numbers" array at the beggining of your code.

You can create a constant one (will not change the content) using:

```
let numbers = [6,4,4]
```

or you can create:

```
var numbers = [6,4,4]
```

this second one, you can change the content.